# Executing bash script multiple times with arguments from file

Tags: bash, file, arguments

I want to run a bash script multiple times with 1 argument at a time, read from a file. That file contains domainnames per line.
The script needs to run as many times as there are domainnames in the ARGUMENTS.txt file with 1 domainname as argument at a time.

I tried running, but this fails:

```
while read -r line; do sh SCRIPTNAME.sh "$line"; done <ARGUMENTS.txt
```

Any idea how this can be done? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did it fail? That looks fine. My first guess would be that `ARGUMENTS.txt` has DOS line endings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please

Comment: Hi chepner, I already check that, to make sure it doesn't has DOS line endings I ran dos2unix on it.

Answer (score 0):

Already found the issue, I already used the variable $line into the script I tried to run... When changing this variable to a different name, the script ran perfectly fine :-)